# Error 404 for xmlrpc call on magento

Tags: php, magento, web, service

I am having error with xml-rpc, user and role is correct

The endpoints are correct

SOAP API Endpoint: https://mymagentosite.com/api/soap
 REST API Endpoint: https://mymagentosite.com/api/rest

But when I try
https://mymagentosite.com/api/xmlrpc it shows a `404`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix

1. Open the file `lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Server.php` (it should be located at the root Magento directory).
2. Find the piece of code

   `if(!$matched){
      #require_once 'Zend/XmlRpc/Server/Exception.php';
      throw new Zend_XmlRpc_Server_Exception('Calling parameters do not match signature',623);
    }`
3. And comment it out

   /*if(!$matched){#require_once 'Zend/XmlRpc/Server/Exception.php';
              throw new Zend_XmlRpc_Server_Exception('Calling parameters do not match signature',623);}*/